# Tourist visa for Hong Kong as an Indian

Tags: indian-citizens, hong-kong, visas-on-arrival, fees-and-charges, tourist-visas

I am planning to go Hong Kong and stay there for 4-6 days and I know that Indians can enter into Hong Kong without tourist visa up to 14 days, is there any other rules to be followed for that. Is only a flight ticket needed to go Hong Kong? Please tell me the approximate fees and charges too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on the immigration department website, Indian can enter HK **without visa for 14days.**

All vistors are required to hold **onward or return** tickets unless they are **transit to Mainland China/Macau**. However, the immigration officers may argue that you may work in HK and thus reject your entry, so you may have to prepare a flight/ship/rail ticket to Macau/Mainland China.

See here for further information:

http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html

Comment: So, is it need to have a China/Macau visa ? @Him

Comment: If ypu font go there you dont need

Comment: is there any need for transit visa?

Comment: @Rengasamy No..

Comment: @rengasamy all transit are 7 days visa free, no matter where are you frim